# Exclude records after a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks as follows:

```
Descr     Chg       PayAmount      AssoChgID
Late Fee  0         450            5
Late Fee  0         -450           5
Late Fee  0         450            5
Late Fee  0         -450           5
AMFA      0         -20            9
AMFA      0         40             9
```

I'm writing a query that would sum up all the `PayAmount` values and group them by their `AssocChgID` and `Descr`. I want to exclude a row if the ending result is `0`.

So for the above I have:

```sql
SELECT Descr, Chg, SUM(PayAmount), AssocChgID  FROM tmpTable t
GROUP BY t.Descr, t.Chg, t.AssocChgID
```

The end result would include a row where the `PayAmount` is `0`:

```
Descr     Chg       PayAmount      AssoChgID
Late Fee  0         0              5
AMFA      0         20             9
```

How can I update my query so that it excludes that row if the `PayAmount` value is equal to `0`?

Comment: The [having](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause might be what you're looking for. Something like `having sum(payamount) <> 0`

Comment: HAVING filter is executed aft GROUPBY

Comment: Yup! Got it working, appreciate it. @BogdanSahlean